# Can I search a HTML table in PHP?

Tags: php

I currently have numerous function which all display the results into a table for example:

```
foreach($matches as $child) { 
    echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo $child . "<br />";
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Is there a way that I can search this table for a keyword and display the results on a button click?

```
   if(isset($_POST['Apply1']))
    {




    }
```

Comment: Sure, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP, you need to pass parameters and search Database accordingly.

With JS its easy:

Use [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/)

This will search table with JS.

You can also add server backend to this to avoid huge PHP code/stying etc.

Comment: I have tried to use Datatables but I can't get it to display any search results. @Pupil

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. On keyUp it will search all `<td>` with `class="Filter"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filter").keyup(function () {

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;

        // Loop through the comment list
        $("tr .Filter").each(function () {

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut(0).addClass('hidden');

                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).parents("tr").show().removeClass('hidden');
                count++;
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>

<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" class="text-input left" id="filter" placeholder="Search" />

    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td class='Filter'>Jill</td>
            <td class='Filter'>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='Filter'>Eve</td>
            <td class='Filter'>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</body>
</html>
```